# String Contains IgnoreCase in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

In C# there is a a problem: there is no case insensitive `String.Contains` method (see [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444798/185593)).

In VB.NET the problem is the same, but there are a workaround:

```
Dim Str As String = "UPPERlower"
Dim b As Boolean = InStr(Str, "UpperLower")
```

However, I have little "problems" with it :

1) In the *Immediate Window* of Visual Studio this method appear as
    "not declared";

2) How can I call this method *dynamically* (what
    should be the "caller" object) ? Say actually I should call it like this:

```
expr = Expression.Call(myStringParam, "Contains", Nothing, constantExpression, Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

3) Where is located (who owns, what assembley) the `InStr` Function?

Comment: What do you mean by "call this method dynamically" exactly? As for the immediate window, I suspect it can't handle extension methods, basically....

Comment: @Jon Skeet: He means invoking it as an instance method.

Comment: @serhio: Right. Mentioning expression trees would have helped :) Have added an answer showing how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having seen your edit, it makes more sense - you can't call an extension method like that. The extension method is *just* a static method, so call it that way. For example:

```
expr = Expression.Call(GetType(MyExtensions), "Contains", Nothing, _
           myStringParam, constantExpression, _
           Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

where `MyExtensions` is the class declaring the `Contains` extension method.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Remark, in VB.NEt the things are a little more complicated... because an extension method can be declared in a Module, not just a shared class... Hope will work with a module too...

Comment: @serhio: I believe a module will be compiled to a static class anyway - look in Reflector.

Comment: apropos, what about `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.InStr` on that chapter? I suppose the same thing but `GetType(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings)`... @Jon Skeet: works very well with module, a propos ;)

Comment: @serhio: Yes, you could probably do the same thing with `InStr`.

Answer (score 8):

(I see now that your question also deals with Expressions, and I do not have much experience with those specifically, but thankfully Jon Skeet may be able to help you with that. As for other parts of your problem, my original answer is below.)

---

`InStr` exists inside `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings`. An example of invoking it from C# code

```
string myString = "Hello World";
int position = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.InStr(myString, "world");
```

Of course, if I wanted a case-insensitive result, I would opt for the overload of `IndexOf` that exists on `System.String` that allows me to specify a `StringComparison`.

```
int index = myString.IndexOf("world", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Also note that `InStr` starts at 1 for items found, and `IndexOf` starts at 0 for such items. `index != position` in this code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate window of Visual Studio is a bit different than normal execution of the method from a compiled program.  It's little different than executing the extension method under the debugger (really it's the same).

This was not well supported in Visual Studio 2005 or 2008.  There's not a lot that can be done there to make it work other than call it by it's non-extension method form

```
TheModule.Contains(source, toTest)
```

The support for it is much improved in 2010 and I would expect it to work.

Comment: @serhio can you add the definition of the `Contains` method then to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can take Anthony's suggestion and make an extension method (or just a normal method) and use IndexOf:

```
<Extension()>
Public Shared Function CaseInsensitiveContains(source As String, value As String) As Boolean
    Return source.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
End Function
```

Comment: this is exactly what I used when explained the question 2) of the post. ) Just coded it in VB.NET )

Comment: missed a `_` ) after Extension )

Comment: _ not required in this case. (VB 2010)